# Route between two points in Android Studio (Java) using the Maps Directions API

Tags: java, android, api

I have the following code, which has the purpose of showing the route between a point 'A' and a point 'B', the initial point 'A' is originated by the current location of the device, while the point 'B' is generated when the user touches a point other than the starting point on the map, I clarify it is a MapView. But the problem is that when using the button responsible for generating the route between both points, it is not displayed / shown on the screen. The strange thing is that when checking my Cloud, if the Directions usage count goes up with each attempt to use the button, at this point I have no idea what it could be, I hope someone can help me, thanks.

PS: I speak Spanish but I translated this with a translator, sorry if there is a spelling mistake

Implementations of my build.gradle file (Some are from other activities, ignore):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.17.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RutaLocal">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRuta"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="@string/calcular_ruta"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</fragment>
```

Manifest (permissions and API KEY):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="Here is my api key, but obviously it is not possible for me to show it"/>
```

Class:

```
package com.example.mapa;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.example.mapa.databinding.RutaLocalBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.maps.DirectionsApi;
import com.google.maps.DirectionsApiRequest;
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.PendingResult;
import com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil;
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsResult;
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsRoute;
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsStep;
import com.google.maps.model.TravelMode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RutaLocal extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private RutaLocalBinding binding;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Polyline routePolyline;
    private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = RutaLocalBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Button btnRuta = binding.btnRuta;
        btnRuta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LatLng currentLocation = getCurrentLocation();
                LatLng destination = getDestinationLocation();

                if (currentLocation != null && destination != null) {
                    getDirections(currentLocation, destination);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RutaLocal.this, "No hay puntos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RutaLocal.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RutaLocal.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 100);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RutaLocal.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RutaLocal.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            }, 100);
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private LatLng getCurrentLocation() {
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ubicación actual")) {
                return marker.getPosition();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private LatLng getDestinationLocation() {
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            if (marker.getTitle().equals("Destino")) {
                return marker.getPosition();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling ActivityCompat#requestPermissions

            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
                    if (location != null) {

                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Ubicación actual"));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15));

                        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                                mMap.clear();
                                markers.clear();
                                LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                Marker currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Ubicación actual"));
                                markers.add(currentMarker);
                                Marker destinationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Destino"));
                                markers.add(destinationMarker);
                                getDirections(currentLocation, point);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getDirections(LatLng origin, LatLng destination) {

        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey("API Key, again")
                .build();

        DirectionsApiRequest request = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context)
                .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(origin.latitude, origin.longitude))
                .destination(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude));

        request.setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                if (routePolyline != null) {
                    routePolyline.remove();
                }

                DirectionsRoute route = result.routes[0];
                List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DirectionsStep step : route.legs[0].steps) {
                    points.add(new LatLng(
                            step.startLocation.lat,
                            step.startLocation.lng
                    ));
                }

                PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(points)
                        .color(Color.BLUE)
                        .width(5);
                routePolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

As I said before, I don't know the reason why it doesn't show me the polyline, I even tried to add Logs to validate in LogCat if the button was calling the appropriate method and if the rest of the methods worked correctly, everything normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to draw polyline on `Main` or `UI` thread?
Try drawing it on main thread and check if API call response is happening on the background thread.

If it is, then simply put `polyline` code into the main thread and you'll get it working perfectly!

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed, it was a matter of putting it in the main thread. Thank you seriously, I've been killing my head for hours